# How to generate Items list with vue-paypal-checkout?

Tags: vue.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, vue-paypal-check

I am trying to generate an items list response from paypal checkout requests. I am trying to do it dynamically, using my data objects and some computed properties in a **for in** loop. As far as I have understood,  my items_list will always need to be a data variable, never a hard-coded array.

Here is my template element:

```
<div v-bind:key="plan.key" v-for="plan in plans" >  
    <PayPal 
        :amount="plan.price" // all good
        currency="GBP" // all good
        :client="credentials" // all good
        env="sandbox" // all good
        :items="[plan]"  // this is NOT working
        @payment-authorized="payment_authorized_cb" // all good
        @payment-completed="payment_completed_cb" // all good
        @payment-cancelled="payment_cancelled_cb"   // all good  
   >
   </PayPal> 
</div>
```

Here are my data objects on my script:

```
 plans: {
        smallPlan: {
            name: 'Small Venue',
            price: '6',
        },
        mediumPlan: {
            name: 'Medium Department',
            price: '22',

        }, 
}
payment_completed: {
    payment_completed_cb() {
    }
},
payment_authorized: {
    payment_authorized_cb() {
    }
},
payment_cancelled: {
    payment_cancelled_cb() {
    }
},
```

Here are my methods:

```
methods: {
payment_completed_cb(res, planName){
    toastr.success("Thank you! We'll send you a confirmation email soon with your invoice. ");
    console.log(res);  
},
payment_authorized_cb(res){
    console.log(res); 
},
payment_cancelled_cb(res){
    toastr.error("The payment process has been canceled. No money was taken from your account.");
    console.log(res); 
},
```

The documentation of Vue-paypal-checkout is available here https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-paypal-checkout

If I don't add the items list **:items** everything works perfectly:

> > {"id":"PAY-02N9173803167370DLPMKKZY","intent":"sale","state":"approved","cart":"90B34422XX075534E","create_time":"2018-10-30T18:39:51Z","payer":{"payment_method":"paypal","status":"VERIFIED","payer_info":{"email":"joaoalvesmarrucho-buyer@gmail.com","first_name":"test","middle_name":"test","last_name":"buyer","payer_id":"JCZUFUEQV33WU","country_code":"US","shipping_address":{"recipient_name":"test buyer","line1":"1 Main St","city":"San Jose","state":"CA","postal_code":"95131","country_code":"US"}}},"transactions":[{"amount":{"total":"245.00","currency":"GBP","details":{}},"item_list":{},"related_resources":[{"sale":{"id":"2RA79134UX2301839","state":"pending","payment_mode":"INSTANT_TRANSFER","protection_eligibility":"ELIGIBLE","parent_payment":"PAY-02N9173803167370DLPMKKZY","create_time":"2018-10-30T18:39:50Z","update_time":"2018-10-30T18:39:50Z","reason_code":"RECEIVING_PREFERENCE_MANDATES_MANUAL_ACTION","amount":{"total":"245.00","currency":"GBP","details":{"subtotal":"245.00"}}}}]}]}

But if I add  :items="[plan]" i get this error message:

> > Uncaught Error: Error: Request to post https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment failed with 400 error. Correlation id: 19238526650f5, 19238526650f5
> >
> > {
> >         "name": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
> >         "details": [
> >             {
> >                 "field": "transactions.item_list.items.item_key",
> >                 "issue": "This field name is not defined for this resource type"
> >             }
> >         ],
> >         "message": "Invalid request - see details",
> >         "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors",
> >         "debug_id": "19238526650f5"

Any thoughts?

Also if you happen to know, is there a way to sell/implement a subscription instead of a one-off transaction using Vue-paypal-checkout?

Many thanks

Comment: Looks like a syntax error, to start with. Should be `:items="plan.name"`.

Comment: Thank you but no luck. It's more complicated than that. I have added more information after I have corrected that typo.

Comment: According to [PayPal doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#definition-item) your items should also have `quantity` & `currency` properties, as they are required. Try adding them and see if anything changes.